# (sen)depende de + ĉu

Tags: word-usage

Konsideru la jenajn frazojn:

1) *Li venos sendepende de tio, ĉu pluvos aŭ ne.*

2) *Li venos sendepende de ĉu pluvos aŭ ne.*

3) *Li venos sendepende ĉu pluvos aŭ ne.*

La 1) estas sendube ĝusta. Mi preskaŭ ĉiam esprimas min laŭ la 3), ĉar mi iel pensas ke la *de* en la 2) estas superflua, fakte tiom superflua, ke al mi ĝi sonas malĝuste. Tamen, tio estas mia persona tute subjektiva impreso pro mia kutimo ne uzi ĝin. Sed nun mi vidas ke la 2) estas multe pli uzata nuntempe, almenaŭ tion montras Google. La problemo estas ke mi ne povas trovi ian klarigon pri tio. En Tekstaro mi ne trovis eĉ unu frazon kun *(sen)depende de* + *ĉu*, sed gugla serĉo donis 15.900 trafojn por *sendepende de ĉu* kontraŭ 1.460 por *sendepende ĉu*. Mi vere opinias ke la tri esprimoj estas ĝustaj. Mia demando estas: ĉu la ĉeesto aŭ foresto de la *de* donas ian rimarkindan nuancon (en la 2-a kaj 3-a frazoj)? Estus ankaŭ interese scii ĉu vi preferas uzi (aŭ ne) la *de* en tiaj frazoj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kaj 1) kaj 3) estas ĝustaj, en 3) simple la esprimo *de tio* estas subkomprenata.

Tamen la frazo 2) laŭ mi estas malĝusta, sendepende de tio, ĉu oni opinias ĝin elipsa (do sen *tio*) aŭ ke la *ĉu*-a subfrazo rekte dependas de *de*. En la unua okazo oni devas ellasi ankaŭ la prepozicion, ĉar ĝi ne povas aperi memstare (kp. PMEG [ĉi tie](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/memstaraj_rolvortetoj.html) kaj [ĉi tie](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/da/nekutimaj_uzoj.html#i-ie4)), en la dua okazo oni havus unikan okazon, ke subpropozicio kun *ĉu* dependas de prepozicio, dum ĉiuj aliaj tiaj okazoj enhavas la subjunkcion *ke* (kp. pri tio denove [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/komplemento.html#i-knp)) - kaj tio estas tute senchava, ĉar la rolo de *ke* estas ĝuste nur montri, ke sekvas frazo en la rolo de sintagmo. Dependigi alian subpropozicion de prepozicio estus io tute sen tradicia modelo. Se ne erara, mi opinias tion almenaŭ tre nekutima (krom se vi denaske parolas angle) kaj evitinda.

Comment: Do, oni ne prenu la kvanton de guglaj trafoj kiel imitindan modelon sed eble kiel tendencon de uzado, kiu ĉi-kaze estas dubinda. Mi ne scias de kie venas mia impreso, ke _de ĉu_ sonas malbone, sed certe ne de la hispana, ĉar hispane oni ja diradas _sendepende de ĉu_ (_independientemente de si_), kion la oficiala gramatiko sankcias kiel ĝustan.

Comment: Google ne estas fidinda fonto por la normo en E-o, ĉar la Interreto enhavas nekredeblan kvanton de malbona aŭ malĝusta E-a lingvaĵo. Se vi ne trovas ion en la Fundamento aŭ (poste) PMEG, faru korpusan serĉon en Tekstaro.com, kiu enhavas ja ne senerarajn, sed ĝenerale bonkvalitajn tekstojn.